# Toggle visibility of 2 elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function clickMe() {
  $('.hidden').toggle();
  $('.visible').toggle();
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden
}
.visible {
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class='hidden'>HiddenLabel</label>
<label class='visible'>VisibileLabel</label>

<button onClick='clickMe()'>Click me</button>
```

This works well for the visible label, but not for the hidden one, as it toggles the visbility of the 'VisibleLabel', but the visibility of the 'HiddenLabel' remains unchanged (hidden).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to swap the classes, and not the visibility. You should use [`.toggleClass`](//api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
function clickMe() {
  $('.hidden, .visible').toggleClass("hidden visible");
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
function clickMe() {
  $('.hidden, .visible').toggleClass("hidden visible");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden
}
.visible {
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class='hidden'>HiddenLabel</label>
<label class='visible'>VisibileLabel</label>

<button onClick='clickMe()'>Click me</button>
```

The reason being, the function `.toggle()` alone can do the thing what you are trying to do, but now you need to toggle the classes and not the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The [`jQuery.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) changes the css-property `display`.

And **not** the css-property `visibility`.

Try instead:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP needs this, does he? Did you understand the question?

Comment: @PraveenKumar. From OP: _This works well for the visible label, but not for the hidden one._ I've explained why it doesn't work. Do you think I am wrong?

Comment: The `Try instead` section is wrong. He's expecting this: http://i.imgur.com/1RAh0gZ.png

Comment: Sorry buddy, do you agree? If not, let me know. :)

Comment: If so, I will vote you up. LoL. If you have a point, why should I deny then.